# Challenging integral with root in denominator

Tags: integration

I'm wondering if anyone has ideas to get started with this integral:

$$
I = \frac{b}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left[(x-1)^2+b^2\right]\left[(x+1)^2+b^2\right]}}
$$

for $b>0$. Mathematica 12 can't get it done (except for $b=1$) and the most obvious methods haven't worked for me. Ideas? Can it be done exactly?

Ben

Edit: Here is a variation that I also would like to solve:

$$
I_2 = \frac{\sqrt{b_+ b_-}}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left[(x-1)^2+b_+^2\right]\left[(x+1)^2+b_-^2\right]}}
$$

I'm not sure that [ComplexYetTrivial](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/570419/complexyettrivial)'s solution will work for this one. There is a linear term appearing in the root that will mess up the square completion. Ideas?

Edit 2: It seems like it was solved here using Maple, but the solution looks quite messy:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/243943/is-it-correct-to-compute-bhattacharyya-distance-for-cauchy-like-bell-shaped-fun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{b}{\pi} \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\sqrt{[(x-1)^2 + b^2][(x+1)^2+b^2]}} = \frac{2b}{\pi} \int \limits_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\sqrt{[(x-1)^2 + b^2][(x+1)^2+b^2]}} \\
&= \frac{2b}{\pi} \int \limits_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\sqrt{(1+b^2)^2 - 2 (1-b^2) x^2 + x^4}} \stackrel{x = \sqrt{1+b^2} t}{=} \frac{2 b}{\pi \sqrt{1+b^2}} \int \limits_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d} t}{\sqrt{1 - 2 \frac{1-b^2}{1+b^2} t^2 + t^4}} \\
&= \frac{2 b}{\pi \sqrt{1+b^2}} \int \limits_0^\infty \!\! \frac{\mathrm{d} t}{\sqrt{(1 + t^2)^2 - \frac{4}{1+b^2} t^2}} \!\stackrel{t = \tan\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)}{=} \!\!\frac{b}{\pi \sqrt{1+b^2}} \int \limits_0^\pi \!\frac{\mathrm{d} \phi}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{4}{1+b^2}\sin^2\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)\cos^2\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)}} \\
&= \frac{b}{\pi \sqrt{1+b^2}} \int \limits_0^\pi \frac{\mathrm{d} \phi}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{\sin^2(\phi)}{1+b^2}}} = \frac{2 b}{\pi \sqrt{1+b^2}} \int \limits_0^{\pi/2} \!\frac{\mathrm{d} \phi}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{\sin^2(\phi)}{1+b^2}}} = \frac{2b}{\pi \sqrt{1+b^2}} \operatorname{K}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\right)
\end{align}
for $b>0$, where $\operatorname{K}$ is the [complete elliptic integral of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think you might have made a mistake in the last identification. I get that the answer is $(2/\pi) K(-1/b^2)$. Unless we're using different definitions of $K$, but I'm it looks the same to me. Anyway, regardless, it works.

Comment: @Ben According to the first identity [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticK/17/01/) (with $z = \frac{1}{1+b^2}$) the two expressions are equal. Note, however, that the Wolfram functions site uses an additional square in the argument of the elliptic integrals compared to Wikipedia and my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that must have been the difference. I'll stick with the most compact answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found [an answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/236661/integral-for-bhattacharyya-distance-between-two-cauchy-distributions) to my suggested generalization for $b_+ \neq b_-$. The result is:

$$I = \frac{4}{\pi}\sqrt{\frac{b_+ b_-}{A_+}} K\left(\frac{A_-}{A_+}\right).$$

Here, I have introduced:

$$A_\pm = 4 + (b_+ \pm b_-)^2,$$

and $K$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind as defined by Mathematica's `EllipticK[]`.